# MongoDB, remove nested doc in an array

Tags: mongodb

I have the following structure in MongoDB and I try to remove the documents that contains specific tags. I can't seem to be able to get the `$pull` work.

In this example, I would like to pull the nested doc that has has tags :`["BB"]`
Any help will be appreciated !

```
{
    "_id": 123,
    "socialItems": {
        "facebook": [{
            "name": "firstFacebook",
            "id": 2
        }, {
            "name": "secondFB",
            "id": 43
        }],
        "instagram": [{
            "name": "firstNstagram",
            "id": 4
        }],
        "pc": [{
            "name": "firstPC",
            "id": 55,
            "tags": [
                "ab"
            ]
        }, {
            "name": "secondPC",
            "id": 66,
            "tags": [
                "BB"
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to drop the nested 'pc' doc, from the array?  You also don't mention if you're using a specific driver for this, so I've assumed you're running this in the Mongo shell.

The following will remove documents from the 'pc' property, when containing the 'BB' tag.

```
db.collectionName.update({'socialItems.pc.tags': 'BB'}, {$pull: {'socialItems.pc': {tags: 'BB'}}})
```